# C++ program behaves differently on MacOS and Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, macos, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

Me and one of my colleague are trying to simulate the three body problem with a C++ program in order to compare different integration schemes. At the moment we are trying to use the Euler's method, but the same program gives us different results on MacOs and windows 10, and we do not understand why.
We are compiling the program launching g++ from the terminal.

The problem is the following:
At a certain point the acceleration of one body computed on Windows becomes infinite, while in the same exactly script this fact doesn't happen on MacOS. [image: different behave on mac (left) and windows (right)]

All the data are stored in three .csv files, and the code is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <array>
#include <fstream>

#define DIM 4
#define G  10//6.67408e-11
#define N_BODIES 3
#define N_STEPS 1000


float acceleration(float mass_1, float mass_2, float pos_1, float pos_2, float pos_3){ 
    //compute the acceleration along one axis of the body 3
    return -1 * G * (mass_1 * (pos_3-pos_1) / pow(abs(pos_3-pos_1), 3) + mass_2 * (pos_3-pos_2) / pow(abs(pos_3-pos_2), 3));
}

int main(){
    
    double mass_1 = 10, mass_2 = 20, mass_3 = 30;                       
    double x0_1[DIM-1] = {-10, 10, -11}, x0_2[DIM-1] = {0, 0, 0}, x0_3[DIM-1] = {10, 14, 12};                                  
    double v0_1[DIM-1] = {-3, 0, 0}, v0_2[DIM-1] = {0, 0, 0}, v0_3[DIM-1] = {3, 0, 0};                                 
    double h = 0.0005;

    double time[N_STEPS], x_1[DIM][N_STEPS], x_2[DIM][N_STEPS], x_3[DIM][N_STEPS], v_1[DIM][N_STEPS], v_2[DIM][N_STEPS], v_3[DIM][N_STEPS], a_1[DIM][N_STEPS], a_2[DIM][N_STEPS], a_3[DIM][N_STEPS];
          


    x_1[0][0] = x0_1[0];
    x_2[0][0] = x0_2[0];
    x_3[0][0] = x0_3[0];

    v_1[0][0] = v0_1[0];
    v_2[0][0] = v0_2[0];
    v_3[0][0] = v0_3[0];

    x_1[1][0] = x0_1[1];
    x_2[1][0] = x0_2[1];
    x_3[1][0] = x0_3[1];

    v_1[1][0] = v0_1[1];
    v_2[1][0] = v0_2[1];
    v_3[1][0] = v0_3[1];

    x_1[2][0] = x0_1[2];
    x_2[2][0] = x0_2[2];
    x_3[2][0] = x0_3[2];

    v_1[2][0] = v0_1[2];
    v_2[2][0] = v0_2[2];
    v_3[2][0] = v0_3[2];



//Function for the Euler method

for (int i=0; i<N_STEPS-1; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<DIM-1; j++){
    a_1[j][i] = acceleration(mass_2, mass_3, x_2[j][i], x_3[j][i], x_1[j][i]);
    a_2[j][i] = acceleration(mass_1, mass_3, x_1[j][i], x_3[j][i], x_2[j][i]);
    a_3[j][i] = acceleration(mass_1, mass_2, x_1[j][i], x_2[j][i], x_3[j][i]);
    
    v_1[j][i + 1] = v_1[j][i] + a_1[j][i] * h;
    v_2[j][i + 1] = v_2[j][i] + a_2[j][i] * h;
    v_3[j][i + 1] = v_3[j][i] + a_3[j][i] * h;
    
    x_1[j][i + 1] = x_1[j][i] + v_1[j][i] * h;
    x_2[j][i + 1] = x_2[j][i] + v_2[j][i] * h;
    x_3[j][i + 1] = x_3[j][i] + v_3[j][i] * h;
    
    }
    
}

    
    std::ofstream output_file_A("positions_A.csv");
    std::ofstream output_file_B("positions_B.csv");
    std::ofstream output_file_C("positions_C.csv");
    output_file_A<<"x;y;z"<<std::endl;
    output_file_B<<"x;y;z"<<std::endl;
    output_file_C<<"x;y;z"<<std::endl;
    

    for(int i = 0; i<N_STEPS-1; i++){
        output_file_A << a_1[0][i] << ";" << a_1[1][i] << ";" << a_1[2][i]<< std::endl;
        output_file_B << a_2[0][i] << ";" << a_2[1][i] << ";" << a_2[2][i]<< std::endl;
        output_file_C << a_3[0][i] << ";" << a_3[1][i] << ";" << a_3[2][i]<< std::endl;
    }    
    output_file_A.close();
    output_file_B.close(); 
    output_file_C.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for your answer!

We expected to obtain the same results on both the different computers, since the code is the same.

Comment: Because you've tagged this C++, you shouldn't declare your constants as macros.

Comment: Notice that you use `float` in the `acceleration` function but `double` inside `main`.

Comment: Different behaviour with different compilers and/or different platforms etc makes my crystal ball say: Probably [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) somewhere..

Comment: Why C-style arrays in C++ in 2022? What's wrong with `std::array` or `std::vector`?

Comment: @JesperJuhl Baby steps.

Comment: Hmm, is it just me or does `#define G  10//6.67408e-11` look wrong? You define G to be `10` followed by a comment `//` ... Also; *why macros*? Yuck.

Comment: And @JesperJuhl, that math is not surrounded by round brackets either, so when substituted in, who knows what may occur?

Comment: @KevinAnderson "who knows what may occur?" - We do know what will happen. The language is definited quite rigorously - including the preprocessor.

Comment: @JesperJuhl more "who knows how it could be mis-used unexpectedly" is what I meant, rather than implying that compilers give random output.

Answer (score 3):

The problem stems entirely from using `abs` in the `acceleration` function instead of `fabs` or `std::abs`. The C function `abs` takes an `int` argument (instead of a double) and returns an `int`.

the C++ compiler contains several overloads of `std::abs` for different numeric types, but if you don't qualify it with the namespace or a using declaration, the compiler will pick the C function. GCC on MacOS fooled you by bringing `std::abs` into the global namespace.  It's possible a compiler switch caused this.

The compiler's choice of `int abs(int)` caused the subexpressions that used it to return incorrect results. `std::abs(pos_3-pos_2)` might become `0` easily, so dividing by `pow(std::abs(pos_3-pos_2), 3)` might become division by zero.

This is made worse by the fact incorrect output from one step is fed into the next step.

To fix this, and some of the other problems mentioned in the comments, the following code produces the expected output in GCC and clang:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>     
#include <array>
#include <fstream>

static constexpr int  DIM =4;
static constexpr double G = 10;
static constexpr int N_BODIES = 3;
static constexpr int N_STEPS = 1000;


double acceleration(double mass_1, double mass_2, double pos_1, double pos_2, double pos_3){ 
    //compute the acceleration along one axis of the body 3
    return -1 * G * (mass_1 * (pos_3-pos_1) / pow(std::abs(pos_3-pos_1), 3) + mass_2 * (pos_3-pos_2) / pow(std::abs(pos_3-pos_2), 3));
}

int main(){
    
    double mass_1 = 10;
    double mass_2 = 20;
    double mass_3 = 30;                       
    double x0_1[DIM-1] = {-10, 10, -11};
    double x0_2[DIM-1] = {0, 0, 0};
    double x0_3[DIM-1] = {10, 14, 12};                                  
    double v0_1[DIM-1] = {-3, 0, 0};
    double v0_2[DIM-1] = {0, 0, 0};
    double v0_3[DIM-1] = {3, 0, 0};                                 
    double h = 0.0005;

    double time[N_STEPS];
    double x_1[DIM][N_STEPS];
    double x_2[DIM][N_STEPS];
    double x_3[DIM][N_STEPS];
    double v_1[DIM][N_STEPS];
    double v_2[DIM][N_STEPS];
    double v_3[DIM][N_STEPS];
    double a_1[DIM][N_STEPS];
    double a_2[DIM][N_STEPS];
    double a_3[DIM][N_STEPS];

    x_1[0][0] = x0_1[0];
    x_2[0][0] = x0_2[0];
    x_3[0][0] = x0_3[0];

    v_1[0][0] = v0_1[0];
    v_2[0][0] = v0_2[0];
    v_3[0][0] = v0_3[0];

    x_1[1][0] = x0_1[1];
    x_2[1][0] = x0_2[1];
    x_3[1][0] = x0_3[1];

    v_1[1][0] = v0_1[1];
    v_2[1][0] = v0_2[1];
    v_3[1][0] = v0_3[1];

    x_1[2][0] = x0_1[2];
    x_2[2][0] = x0_2[2];
    x_3[2][0] = x0_3[2];

    v_1[2][0] = v0_1[2];
    v_2[2][0] = v0_2[2];
    v_3[2][0] = v0_3[2];



    //Function for the Euler method

    for (int i=0; i<N_STEPS-1; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<DIM-1; j++)
        {
         a_1[j][i] = acceleration(mass_2, mass_3, x_2[j][i], x_3[j][i], x_1[j][i]);
         a_2[j][i] = acceleration(mass_1, mass_3, x_1[j][i], x_3[j][i], x_2[j][i]);
         a_3[j][i] = acceleration(mass_1, mass_2, x_1[j][i], x_2[j][i], x_3[j][i]);
    
         v_1[j][i + 1] = v_1[j][i] + a_1[j][i] * h;
         v_2[j][i + 1] = v_2[j][i] + a_2[j][i] * h;
         v_3[j][i + 1] = v_3[j][i] + a_3[j][i] * h;
    
         x_1[j][i + 1] = x_1[j][i] + v_1[j][i] * h;
         x_2[j][i + 1] = x_2[j][i] + v_2[j][i] * h;
         x_3[j][i + 1] = x_3[j][i] + v_3[j][i] * h;
    
        }



    for(int i = 500; i<N_STEPS-1; i++){
        std::cout << i << ":" << a_1[0][i] << ";" << a_1[1][i] << ";" << a_1[2][i]<< ":";
        std::cout << a_2[0][i] << ";" << a_2[1][i] << ";" << a_2[2][i]<< ":";
        std::cout  << a_3[0][i] << ";" << a_3[1][i] << ";" << a_3[2][i]<< '\n';
    }    
    
    return 0;
}
```